Having a function with the same name as std, how do I explicitly call the function from std?
I create a function with the same name as in std, why when I explicitly call the function std::pow, my pow is called? I tried to make it in Clion, Xcode on Mac, also Rider on windows I got "13" two times(with default compilers), but when I asked my fried to run this in Visual Studio, he got two times std::pow call. Im not using "using namespace std;"
#include <cmath>

double pow(double num, double exponent)
{
    return 13.0;
}

int main()
{
    double a = pow(10, 5);
    double b = std::pow(10, 5);

    return 0;
}


Unless you have using namespace std; (which you should not have) then it's already handled. Otherwise use the scope operator ::, like ::pow(...) to use the one in the global namespace. But if you want to create utility functions then I recommend that you place them in their own namespace.

@Someprogrammerdude Isn't there a problem because pow also exists as a not namespaced variant, and that the std::pow - depending with which types it is called - uses internally that not namespaced one? And that one would be overwritten by the one defined by the OP?

Avoiding using namespace std is good advice but doesn't seem to help in this case. https://godbolt.org/z/szvrEWh8o Personally I'd avoiding naming functions the same at standard functions or putting your functions in their own namespace. Funny, or not, that clang does the exact opposite of what you might expect.

Perhaps in your standard library pow is a weak symbol? If so, there's no way around it, you must rename the function or put it into a namespace. (I for some reason get different answers even on the same OS, with different compilers: GCC vs Clang.) (I wonder how it works in the first place, isn't C++ supposed to mangle the name? Maybe that's the difference.)

If the arguments are doubles instead if ints then clang doesn't call the user provided function at all. https://godbolt.org/z/ofbbo6GqK

Could you provide a [mcve], please? Include the compile command used as well.

@t.niese IIRC it should only happen if <math.h> is included, but I could be wrong.

Side note: Stating which IDE you used is seldom as useful as stating which compiler the IDE used.

@Someprogrammerdude based on N4860 16.5.1.2 Headers (5) I would say that those functions of math.h can exist globally in cmath.

@Someprogrammerdude I actually read it that way that they exist globally, it is just not defined whether the global ones are exposed from the namespace or if they are defined globally and used in the namespace.

Looks like the std::pow(double,double) calls the ::pow(double,double), which is the one you've provided and supersedes the one from the standard library.

Dupes: Can reserved function names be overloaded? and Can a declaration affect the std namespace?

The function with name pow and signature
pow(double, double)

appears in the standard library as a function with external linkage inherited from the C standard library. (See cppreference.)
Function signatures with these properties are reserved in the global namespace scope. A program that declares or defines a function with the same name and signature in the global namespace scope has undefined behavior. See [extern.names]/4 together with [reserved.names.general]/2.
So the question of calling the function doesn't even matter. The program already is invalid for defining that function. A different name must be chosen.
Or better, everything that you define yourself should go into a namespace scope that clearly belongs to yourself. Then you can explicitly qualify your calls with the name of your namespace scope and you won't have to take care of all of the special rules that apply to the global namespace scope, such as the one I explained here.
